# Why an url works on curl but same url isn't working on browser?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have two VM under a project (P1) one is called VM1 and VM2. When trying to ping VM2 from VM1 using internal IP address it works fine and vice versa. I have a REST API on VM1 `http://10.130.0.3:2300/api/list`, now I try to access from VM2 CMD using `curl http://10.130.0.3:2300/api/list` which is providing me desired result. everything is working fine till now.

I have a web application on VM2 which is trying to access VM1 REST API via `axios` `http://10.130.0.3:2300/api/list` from google chrome I am getting network API status as `pending` after some time it changed to `(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. Could anyone please help me out why this is happing?
[click here for GCP VM architecture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2QSA.png)

BTW I am using two internal IPs in the same project with the same subnet. Firewall (ingress) is allowed to 2300 port.

Comment: The chrome browser run on the VM2?

Comment: Apart from the two described VMs, is there a client workstation with Chrome browser outside of the subnetwork 10.130.0.0? If yes, where is it topologically located: in the same or different subnetwork, VPC network, Internet?

Comment: @mebius99 thanks for your reply - Only two are trying to communicate.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - yes VM2 has a web application that I trying to access from google chrome.

Comment: What machine is the Chrome browser executable (`google-chrome` or `chrome.exe`) is launched on: on VM2?

Comment: @Dipak, ok for the web application. But, where run  the chrome browser? On your local machine or on the VM2?

Comment: Apologies I didn't explain to you very well, trying to access VM2 from local machine google chrome using VM2 external IP.

Comment: Well, can you `ping` and `curl` the VM2 external IP from your local workstation where you're launching Crome?

Comment: @mebius99 I can able to access my VM2 web application on google chrome using the external IP address. The problem occurs when trying to access VM1 API to fetch the data using VM1 internal IP.

Comment: Starting from this point the issue does not seem to be related to GCP networking. Something could be wrong with the web app or axios configuration, URL or program code; there are resources out there where developers discuss the connection timeout error caused by non-networking reasons: for example https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/my-webserver-responds-a-private-ip-to-the-internet